# Codeigniter failed set rows and rows textarea

Tags: php, codeigniter, textarea

My view file:

```
echo form_textarea('',$data['note_order'],"rows='4' cols='50'");
```

But what I got in the browser:

```
<textarea name="" cols="90" rows="12">Blablablabla</textarea>
```

If I change view code like:

```
$options = array(
    'rows' => 4,
    'cols' => 50
);
echo form_textarea('',$data['note_order'],$options);
```

I got error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Array to string conversion
Filename: helpers/form_helper.php
Line Number: 265
```

Why my set is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$options = array(
    'name' => '',
    'rows' => '4',
    'cols' => '50',
    'value'=> $data['note_order']
);
echo form_textarea($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
echo form_textarea('notes', set_value('notes'), array('rows' => '3'));
```

results in markup with rows="10"; not what I wanted. Whereas

```
echo form_textarea(array(
        'name' => 'notes',
        'id' => 'notes',
        'value' => set_value('notes'),
        'rows' => '3'
    ));
```

(with or without the id element) correctly produces markup with rows="3".

Answer (score 0):

go to **system/helpers/form_helper** then look for **form_textarea** then comment out

```html
$defaults = array(
   'name' => is_array($data) ? '' : $data,
   // 'cols' => '40', --> this
   // 'rows' => '10' --> this
  );
```